# Difference between a schema and a database in db2

Tags: schema, db2, table

I can not figure out what is the difference between schema and database in db2 I find this SQL so confusing for example :

```
CREATE TABLE schema1.table1
 ....
 ....
 ....
IN database1.tabspace1
```

Can we say that the database in this case contains the tabspace whereas the schema contains the tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This simple question has caused an unusual amount of debate, and I feel compelled to quote [an authoritative source](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc-gentopic3.html?lang=en).

> The *database* stores all data in tables that are related to one another. Relationships are established between tables such that data is shared and duplication is minimized.
>
> A *table space* is a storage structure containing tables, indexes, large objects, and long data. They are used to organize data in a database into logical storage groupings that relate to where data is stored on a system.
>
> A *schema* is a collection of named objects; it provides a way to group those objects logically. A schema is also a name qualifier; it provides a way to use the same natural name for several objects, and to prevent ambiguous references to those objects.

Answer (score 3):

A database is a collection of schemas, a schema is a collection of tables/views/UDF/...

Comment: Not very verbose, but seems correct. Why is this down voted?

Answer (score -1):

schema = namespace within database, identical to user account
database = single database